# Xcode 7 adding private framework Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I keep receiving this error in Xcode 7 while trying to add a private framework to my project. The build fails with the error and log below

[image]

Things I've tried:

1. The framework has been added to the target as both a linked framework & embedded binary, just an embedded binary, and just a linked framework.
2. Build Settings > Enable bitcode has been tried both on and off in both the project and target, only the target, and only the project.
3. I have tried placing the .framework file and package in the original file, within the project package file, and installed to Library/Frameworks
4. I have verified that the search path in build settings has included each of those paths in both the project and target.

I'm at my wits' end and fantasizing about switching to AppCode. Anyone have any other suggestions on what to try?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project and re-compiling it.

That usually solves that error for me.

Comment: Thanks @IrLearn, but I already tried clean and build a few times.